# JSON parsing scratch org username results in "user hasn't approved this consumer"

Tags: python, json, docker, jq, git-bash

I have a problem concerning the json parsing and passing of a username variable to use it from a docker container to authenticate to a salesforce connected app using jwt.

The username is parsed from a temporary json file after a scratch org is created, it is logged and thus saved as variable. However, when passing it to my docker container it won't function, resulting in a "user hasn't approved this consumer" prompt while trying to authenticate. I also tried using python for getting the username - with the same result. When i hard-code the very same username as variable into the script e.g SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME='test-name@email.com' it works everytime. I'm on Win11 working with vscode, executing the shell file with git bash.

This is the jq method i used:

```
SCRATCH_ORG_OUTPUT=$(mktemp)
sf org create scratch --target-dev-hub sfdxdevhub4@ibs-technology.com -f SFDX_Project/config/project-scratch-def.json -y 1 --json > "$SCRATCH_ORG_OUTPUT"

# Extract the username using jq and tr directly in Bash
export SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME=$(jq -r '.result.username' "$SCRATCH_ORG_OUTPUT" | tr -d '\r\n')

# Check if the scratch org creation was successful
if [ -n "$SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME" ]; then
    log "Scratch Org Username: $SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME"
    USERNAME_LENGTH=${#SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME}
    log "Length of Scratch Org Username: $USERNAME_LENGTH"
else
    # Log failure and exit
    log "Scratch org creation failed or username not found"
    cat "$SCRATCH_ORG_OUTPUT" # Display error details
    exit 1
fi

# Cleanup: Remove the temporary file
rm "$SCRATCH_ORG_OUTPUT"
```

This was the python method i used:

```
# Extract the username
SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME=$(python -c "import sys, json; data=json.load(open(sys.argv[1], 'r', encoding='utf-8')); assert 'result' in data and 'username' in data['result'], 'Username not found'; username=data['result']['username'].strip(); print(username)" "$SCRATCH_ORG_OUTPUT")
```

Since both failed and hard-coding works, i assume it might be something underlying, unfortunately i have no idea what to look for.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, what is the value of `SCRATCH_ORG_USERNAME`? Note that all-uppercase variables are reserved and shouldn't be used by custom scripts